# A question that's been bothering me for so long

Tags: java, arrays, object, return

can you return an array? or an array of objects? or return an object? is that really possible? or is that possible? can anyone give me examples? and also can anyone provied me any good links when it comes to good programming practice? OOP specifically since I want to be a good java programmer also can you return user defined classes? like objects with setters and getters? and arrays? and arrays of objects?

```
double Amounts ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} 
for(int i = 0;i<Amounts.length;i++) { 
    Briefcase[i] cases= new Briefcase[]; 
    double x = Amounts[i];
    Briefcase[i].setValue(x); 
} 

public Briefcase[] get(){ 
    return Briefcase[]; 
}
```

Comment: can you return an object? for example like this

double Amounts ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

for(int i = 0;i<Amounts.length;i++)
{
Briefcase[i] cases= new Briefcase[];
double x = Amounts[i]
Briefcase[i].setValue(x);
}

public Briefcase[] get(){
return Briefcase[];
}

is this allowable?

Comment: what is so bothering you about array? it's being return/pass/stuff all over

Comment: yes. 

public List<YourObject> getObjects(){ ... }

Comment: I suggest you should start with a basic Java tutorial.

Comment: I already read a book about java, but I never yet tackled such topic like this, I am reading deitels java early objects, I just wanted to post this question since I think that people with experience can answer me better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in many different ways. Not exactly sure what you are asking, so here are a few examples.

```
public Object[] getArray() { }

public MyObject[] getArray() { }

public List<MyObject> getArray() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific. And I cant imagine how can the simple below code make someone bother so long :)

```
public MyObject[] getArray() {
    return new MyObject[10];
}
```

Comment: not that, I mean user defined objects :D or what if it's like this public Briefcase getCase(){
return Briefcase[15];
}

Briefcase is a user defined object/class

Comment: @Andrew Asmer: you can do that as well: `public Briefcase[] getCase(){ return new Briefcase[15]; }`.

Comment: how about return Briefcase[5]; for example it's value is null, can you return a null valued array?

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the same. but really you need to drink up an entire java book before you start programming in java, that might seem like pain now, but over long time, its good

Comment: you can return an array that contains all null values AND you can even return a null object itself

Comment: null is considered as an ojbect?

Comment: null can be assigned to a object reference of any type

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example of returning an array of user defined objects. HTH.

```
public class Example {
    public static class Composer {
        private final String name;

        Composer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Composer[] composers = getComposers();
        for (Composer composer : composers) {
            System.out.println(composer.getName());
        }
    }

    public static Composer[] getComposers() {
        return new Composer[]{new Composer("Mozart"), new Composer("Pachbel"),
                new Composer("Vivaldi")};
    }
}
```

Comment: There! thanks, sooo you can return it, but what's hte use of new? , if you already created an object of it in the the Composer[] getComposers() ?

Answer (score 2):

Since java is Object oriented language , its made to play around using Objects. returning `array` and

an `Object` does't make any difference in java. An `Array is an Object` after all. So you can return

anything (I mean Arrays, Objects with getters Setters, or Any type of Objects). and that covers even

the classes you create since they are also Objects by default (Since every class you create in java

will Extend Object class by default).

for instance you can do this,

```
Class A{
private int[] arr = {1,2,3};

private A a;

public int[] getArray(){
return arr;
}
public void setA(){
a = new A();
}
public A getA(){
return a;
}

}
```